# C# Need to eliminate " ' " from checkedListBox string so DB connection do not throw exception

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I've been trying to find a way to have my dBConnection to Access ignore the apostrophe (') as it throws an exception. Here is the code I have:

```
public partial class Notifications : Form
{
private void checkedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
            foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox.CheckedItems)
            {
                //This is the line of code I added to try to clean up the " ' "
                filterstring += checkedListBox.Text.Replace("'", "");
                //This line is to select multiple items from column "Responsible" by adding "OR".
                filterstring += " Responsible = '" + itemChecked.ToString() + "' OR";
            }
            filterstring = filterstring.Substring(0, filterstring.LastIndexOf("OR"));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the code keeps throwing me an exception (the name is B'oeckelman)
    [image: exception message]

This is the code that points to the database in case it helps clarify:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                DataTableCollection tables = myDatabaseDataSet.Tables;
                DataView view = new DataView(tables[0]);
                BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
                source.DataSource = view;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
                //Here is where the exception is pointing at.
                source.Filter = filterstring;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you post the contents of `filterstring` at the time the exception is thrown? It doesn't seem like an existent apostrophe is the problem.

Comment: The code works perfect with any other name for as long as it does not have the (')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox.CheckedItems) {
    filterstring += " Responsible = '" + itemChecked.ToString().Replace("'", "") + "' OR";
}
```

The place where the unexpected `'` appears is indeed between the "legal" ones.

However, this kind of input sanitizing is pretty weak and other problems might appear. Obligatory reference to xkcd's [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/). I'm not sure what language this is, but there's certainly a kind of abstraction that would allow you to use prepared statements to make this more robust (and allow you to keep peoples names the way they should be).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I upvoted it as is super useful, but I have to be fair to Saeid as he answered first. Please anyone chime in if it does not seem fair that way...

Comment: @P.C this website does not work on who answered first, it is whatever answer you think is best. I have had questions where I will get a new answer a year later and I switch the accepted answer to it because it is better than the original answer.

Comment: I have to agree with you, it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see that "itemChecked.ToString()"? You should do your replacement there.

This is not your case, but in general, don't inject your code into a string to execute it against SQL Server. Define parameters and set your values to them. Then use those parameters to form your query. Beside this issue, your code may rise SQL Injection security issue.

Comment: That's it. This just happens because you're not using parameters. Building a query this way can be dangerous and harmful.